# Android MapView only scrolling vertically

Tags: android, google-maps, scrollview, android-mapview, nestedscrollview

My Problem: I can just scroll up and down within my MapView, not left and right.

I have a MapView in my LinearLayout, which is holded by a Nested Scroll View. So my layout.xml looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/jd_map_view"/>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm initializing the MapView in my Fragment, holded by a TabLayout, like this:

```
mapView = (MapView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.jd_map_view);
mapView.onCreate(savedInst);
mapView.onResume();
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(mLat, mLng);
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
                CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng);
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14);

                googleMap.moveCamera(center);
                googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);
            }
        });
```

It works more or less correctly, means I see a Map, see my Marker and the Map is on the right Position. But unforunately, I can't scroll right...

Comment: Where do you mean to use the frame layout? instead of the linear layout or as placeholder for the MapFragment?

Comment: It doesn't work :/ Is it possible, that I have to force the NestedScrollView to let the touch through to the MapView?

Comment: Nice, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately not :/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a scroll layout, the map will automatically scroll in any direction if you put it in a simple framelayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="thiscode.databasedemo.Main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        // adjust margins for your need.
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        // etc


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        // adjust margins for your need.
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    // create class object
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    //
    try {
        GoogleMap googleMap =
                ((MapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
        // example data.
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(0.083037, 106.704897);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latlng).zoom(2).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give a try. Just to avoid misunderstanding: I need the NestedScrollView because the Content is too big, not for the Map. I want to have a normal ScrollView with a MapView in it which gets active if I scroll in it.

Comment: Further: I want to show the Map in a Fragment, not in a Activity.